# kotlin:Radio button single check control

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, adapter

i have a simple app that started with RecyclerView fragment and every row have RadioButton but the problem is i cant make only one radio button checked i need it if i check ont after one the old one uncheck automatic 
here is my adapter

```
class StoresAdapter constructor(private val activety: MainActivity, private var listOfData: ArrayList<StoresModeling>,
                            val listener: ContentListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<StoresAdapter.ViewHolder>() {



override fun getItemCount(): Int = listOfData.size
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    //var inf = ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent!!.context).inflate(R.layout.min_mark_modling, parent, false))

    return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent!!.context).inflate(R.layout.stores_tick, parent, false),getItemViewType(transition_position))

}
var selectedPosition:Int = 0
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(listOfData[position], listener, listOfData)

}

inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View?,position: Int) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun bind(Data: StoresModeling, listener: ContentListener, listOfData: ArrayList<StoresModeling>) {

        val dataListin2 = listOfData[adapterPosition]

        var titlein = dataListin2.title
        var cityin = dataListin2.city
        var codein = dataListin2.code


        itemView.title.text = titlein
        itemView.city.text = cityin
        itemView.code.text = codein
        /////// my radioButton /////
        itemView.RB



    }
}


interface ContentListener {
    fun onItemClicked(Data: StoresModeling) {


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple.

**Step 1.** Use `CheckBox` instead `RadioButton` because they can't be unchecked as does say the documentation

> However, contrary to a CheckBox, a radio button cannot be unchecked by the user once checked.

**Step 2.** Create the property `var isChecked: Boolean = false` on your class `StoresModeling`

**Step 3.** Erase all body of your `ViewHolder`(you are using it wrong), write just it

```
class ViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
```

And populate your `StoresModeling` inside your `onBindViewHolder`

**Step 4.** Change state (inside your `onBindViewHolder`) of your `isChecked`, uncheck all others and notify the your adapter by follow code:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
      if (isChecked) {
             data.isChecked = true
             listOfData.forEach {
                    if (!it.equals(data)) it.isChecked = false
             }
             notifyDataSetChanged()
      }
}
```

Comment: I missing under stand some of code im just being in kotlin can you show me how all cod will look like ? As you can edit that code im just posted

Comment: Thank you it work now but i was miss to add the isCheked value in the array